# Build an prediction models with VNP46A2 data VIIRS

Tags: google-earth-engine, google-earth-engine-javascript-api, spatial-predicates, viirs, error-handling

How can I create a Random forest prediction model based on "normalized_NTL_collection" or "normalized_NTL"? I don't understand how to determine the model and input that should be used. Here I tried to export it but got the failure:

> "user memory limited"

This my code (or you can see at my github : https://github.com/dwndnt/Predicting-Poverty-Level.git):

```
// Impor dataset untuk pelatihan dan tes
var dataset = ee.ImageCollection("NOAA/VIIRS/001/VNP46A2")
    .filterDate("2022-01-01", "2022-12-31")
    .select("DNB_BRDF_Corrected_NTL");

// Definisikan wilayah penelitian (misalnya, menggunakan batas administratif Sumatera Utara)
var roi = ee.FeatureCollection("users/dinatadewan/shapefile_sumut");

// Fungsi untuk menghitung statistik
var calculateStatistics = function(image) {
  var statistics = image.reduceRegion({
    reducer: ee.Reducer.mean(),
    geometry: roi,
    scale: 500,
    maxPixels: 1e9
  });
  return image.set(statistics);
};

// Menerapkan fungsi ke setiap citra dalam koleksi
var datasetWithStatistics = dataset.map(calculateStatistics);

// Hitung rata-rata dan deviasi standar dari seluruh citra NTL
var mean_std = datasetWithStatistics.reduceColumns({
  reducer: ee.Reducer.mean().combine({
    reducer2: ee.Reducer.stdDev(),
    sharedInputs: true
  }),
  selectors: ['DNB_BRDF_Corrected_NTL']
});

var mean = mean_std.get('mean');
var stddev = mean_std.get('stdDev');

// Fungsi untuk menghapus cahaya latar belakang dan menormalisasi citra NTL
var normalizeNTL = function(image) {
  var normalized_image = image.subtract(ee.Image.constant(mean)).divide(ee.Image.constant(stddev));
  return normalized_image.set('system:time_start', image.get('system:time_start'));
};

// Ubah citra NTL dengan menghapus cahaya latar belakang dan normalisasi
var normalized_NTL = datasetWithStatistics.map(normalizeNTL);

// Menambahkan layer NTL di wilayah Sumatera Utara ke peta
var vis_params = {
  min: -0.5,  // Sesuaikan dengan ambang batas yang sesuai setelah normalisasi
  max: 4,     // Sesuaikan dengan ambang batas yang sesuai setelah normalisasi
  palette: ['black', 'blue', 'green', 'yellow', 'red', 'white']
};

// Clip layer "Filtered NTL Sumatera Utara" ke wilayah roi
var clipped_NTL = normalized_NTL.map(function(image) {
  return image.clip(roi);
});


Map.centerObject(roi, 7);
Map.addLayer(clipped_NTL, vis_params, "Normalized NTL Sumatera Utara");

// Nama untuk koleksi yang akan disimpan di project/assets
var collectionName = 'Normalized_NTL_Collection';

// Buat koleksi baru dari citra-citra yang telah dinormalisasi
var normalized_NTL_collection = ee.ImageCollection(normalized_NTL);

// Set nama koleksi
normalized_NTL_collection = normalized_NTL_collection.set('collectionName', collectionName);

// Salin properti dari dataset atau normalized_NTL ke koleksi yang akan disimpan
normalized_NTL_collection = normalized_NTL_collection.copyProperties(datasetWithStatistics, ['star']);

// Nama untuk koleksi yang akan disimpan di project/assets
var collectionName = 'Normalized_NTL_Collection';

// Buat koleksi baru dari citra-citra yang telah dinormalisasi
var normalized_NTL_collection = ee.ImageCollection(normalized_NTL);

// Set nama koleksi
normalized_NTL_collection = normalized_NTL_collection.set('collectionName', collectionName);

// Salin properti dari dataset atau normalized_NTL ke koleksi yang akan disimpan
normalized_NTL_collection = normalized_NTL_collection.map(function(image) {
  return image.copyProperties(datasetWithStatistics.first(), ['property_name_to_copy']);
});


print(normalized_NTL_collection)
print(normalized_NTL)
print(clipped_NTL)

var monthly_NTL = normalized_NTL_collection
  .filter(ee.Filter.date('2022-01-01', '2022-02-28'))
  .sort('system:time_start');
var monthly_mean_NTL = monthly_NTL.map(function(image) {
  var year = ee.Number.parse(image.date().format("YYYY"));
  var month = ee.Number.parse(image.date().format("MM"));
  var monthly_mean = monthly_NTL.filterDate(image.date(), image.date().advance(1, 'month'))
    .mean();
  return monthly_mean.set('system:time_start', ee.Date.fromYMD(year, month, 1));
});
var chart = ui.Chart.image.series({
  imageCollection: monthly_mean_NTL.select('DNB_BRDF_Corrected_NTL'),
  region: roi,
  reducer: ee.Reducer.mean(),
  scale: 500
}).setOptions({
  title: 'Perubahan NTL Bulanan di Sumatera Utara (2022)',
  hAxis: {title: 'Waktu'},
  vAxis: {title: 'Rata-rata NTL'},
});

print(chart);
```